# What is wrong with my Heap Sort code in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, heap, heapsort

I'm trying to create and sort a heap using this array in Java. I keep getting an array index out of bounds exception in my maxHeap function. The code seems to make sense to me, so I'm not sure where the error is coming from.

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] array = { 5, 16, 10, 7, 43, 12, 75, 33, 47, 3, 2489, 591, 6639, 557, 84, 9054, 17, 8841, 99, 701, 21, 78, 9, 36, 839};
    heapSort(array3);
    System.out.println("Heap Sort:");
    printArray(array3);
}

public static void createHeap(int []A){
    int n = A.length-1;
    for(int i=n/2;i>=0;i--){
        maxheap(A,i);
    }
}

public static void maxheap(int[] A, int i){ 
    int n = A.length;
    int largest;
    int left=2*i;
    int right=2*i+1;
    if(left <= n && A[left] > A[i]){
        largest=left;
    }
    else{
        largest=i;
    }

    if(right <= n && A[right] > A[largest]){
        largest=right;
    }
    if(largest!=i){
        int temp=A[i];
        A[i]=A[largest];
        A[largest]=temp;
        maxheap(A, largest);
    }
}

public static void heapSort(int []A){
    createHeap(A);
    int n= A.length;
    for(int i=n;i>0;i--){
        int temp=A[0];
        A[0]=A[i];
        A[i]=temp;
        n=n-1;
        maxheap(A, 0);
    }
}


public static void printArray(int[] sortedArray) {

   for (int i = 0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
       System.out.print(sortedArray[i] + ", ");
   }
   System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: What line is the error coming from?

Comment: Please include the full stack trace!

Comment: Look at `<= n` and `i=n`.

Comment: My guess would be here "if(right <= n && A[right] > A[largest])" if right = n, then A[right] is out of bounds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are declaring `int n` three times, first time as:

```
int n = A.length - 1;
```

in `createHeap()`

second time:

```
int n = A.length;
```

in `maxHeap()` and third time:

```
int n = A.length;
```

in `heapSort();`

In `maxHeap()` `right` is set to 25 and therefor `A[right]` (A[25]) is out of bounds

You can leave `int n = A.length` out of both `heapSort()` and `maxHeap()`.

Answer (score 5):

Arrays in Java are [zero-indexed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering). You're setting your loop upper bound (`n`) to be `A.length`, then doing a **less than or equal to** comparison against it, so it will always check for one too many elements.

```
if(left <= n && A[left] > A[i]){
```

Should be

```
if(left < n && A[left] > A[i]){
```

And

```
if(right <= n && A[right] > A[largest]){
```

Should be

```
if(right < n && A[right] > A[largest]){
```

You're also performing a dodgy operation to initialise `right`. `createHeap()` sets `i` to be equal to `n/2` (which is potentially a bug in itself). You then pass this value through to `maxHeap` in the form of the parameter `i`. Then you're doing this:

```
int right = 2*i+1;
```

What happens here when `i` is say, 2?

In order for `i` to be `2`, `A.length` must be `5` or `6` (because `createHeap` sets `n` to be `A.length - 1`, so `(5 - 1) / 2 = 4` as does `(6 - 1) / 2`). When this trickles through to `maxheap`, `2 * i + 1` takes you up to `5`, which is out of bounds of `A` (it may be the length, but if that's the case, then `4` is the highest index, not `5`).

So, this is the situation when `A.length = 5`:

```
if(right <= n && A[right] > A[largest]) {
   ^ 5      ^ 5    ^ ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException thrown here.
```

`right <= n` evaluates to `true`, because `5` does indeed equal `5`, so `A[right]` is evaluated, and promptly fails with your exception. A simple **less than** check on `right < n` would prevent this, as `5` is not less than `5`, so the first condition evaluates to `false`, thereby ensuring that `A[right]` would not get evaluated at all.

In short - this doesn't work for an odd length array.

**Remember:** The `.length` property of an array tells you how many elements that array *can* contain, **not** the index of the last element.

Comment: your explanation would not be the cause of the index out of bounds exception in this case. It is thrown at `A[0] = A[i];` Because of the `&&` operator, if `left` or `i` would be out of bounds it would compute as a false and go to the `else` statement.

Comment: No. If `A[left]` was out of bounds it wouldn't evaluate to `false`, it would throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. `i` cannot be out of bounds as far as I can tell, as `createHeap()` sets it to be `n/2` before passing it in. `right` potentially *can* be out of bounds due to the `2 * i + 1` operation. This code will never reach `A[0] = A[i]` in `heapSort`, it'll die before it does. Had you actually run this code you'd have noticed this.

Comment: Try it. I have debugged it. Only when the condition would be `(A[right] > A[largest] && right <= n)` it throws an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. But not the other way around. Since `left` and `right` can have values bigger than `A.lenght`

Comment: I *did* try it. I have also debugged it, and the code fails on that line because `A[right]` **is out of bounds** as I stated.

Comment: If i debug it and remove `int n = A.length` in the `heapSort()` function, the code runs. Changing it like you say makes no difference. At some point the condition even is `38 <= 24 && A[38] > A[19]` and that doesn't throw an exception.

Comment: So *you're running the wrong code*. You've changed it from what the OP posted, so it's completely irrelevant that yours doesn't fail in the same way. Run the OP's code, you will see exactly where it fails.

Comment: How can you say that? I have copied and pasted the code. And since the OP has accepted my answer, i don't know why you keep saying i am not doing it right.

Comment: You also stated that you removed `int n = A.length`, so you're no longer running the posted code.

Comment: That line is causing the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. If i change to `int n = A.length` in the `maxheap()` function it does throw an exception like you say.

Comment: I haven't criticised your answer at all - it does work. My problem was with your initial comment suggesting that accessing an out of bounds index in the `if` conditional would evaluate to `false` instead of generating the exception. I think we can both agree that there are a number of issues with the original code, we've just simply addressed different ones with our answers.

Comment: You are right about that. I get it now why it doesnt. Even if the second condition should throw an exception, it wont because of the first condition. If the first condition is true, then the second condition will either return true or false and can't throw an exception because `n` can't be bigger then 24. If the first condition is false, then the second condition won't be evaluated, even if it would throw an exception.

Comment: My mistake, i commented out `int n` in `maxHeap()` and overlooked the thrird declaration of n. Stepping through the code it makes it crash where you said it crashed. But still, changing `<=` to `<` is not the solution, that is not what is wrong, `left` can be less than or equal to 24. :)